# Scrapy - Multiple resquest by looping JSON file

Tags: scrapy, web-crawler

I'm trying to get the latitude and longitude of different cities. The name of cities are stored in a JSON file. Here is my code:

```
import scrapy
import json

with open('C:/Users/coppe/tutorial/cities.json') as json_file:  
    cities = json.load(json_file)

class communes_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "geo"
    start_urls = ['https://www.latlong.net/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for city in cities:
            return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'place': city['city']}, callback=self.get_geo)

    def get_geo(self, response):
        yield {response.css('span.coordinatetxt::text').get()}
```

The objective is to loop through the JSON file and for each city send a resquest to a form from the url "https://www.latlong.net/". However nothing is prompting from this request. Is this a bad way to make loop ? Should I treat the JSON file inside the class ?

Log:

```
2019-04-01 16:27:17 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 1.5.1 started (bot: tutorial)
2019-04-01 16:27:17 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.2.5.0, libxml2 2.9.8, cssselect 1.0.3, parsel 1.5.1, w3lib 1.19.0, Twisted 18.9.0, Python 3.7.1 (default, Oct 28 2018, 08:39:03) [MSC v.1912 64 bit (AMD64)], pyOpenSSL 18.0.0 (OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018), cryptography 2.3.1, Platform Windows-10-10.0.17763-SP0
2019-04-01 16:27:17 [scrapy.crawler] INFO: Overridden settings: {'BOT_NAME': 'tutorial', 'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'tutorial.spiders', 'ROBOTSTXT_OBEY': True, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['tutorial.spiders']}
2019-04-01 16:27:17 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled extensions:
['scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats',
 'scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole',
 'scrapy.extensions.logstats.LogStats']
2019-04-01 16:27:17 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.robotstxt.RobotsTxtMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.cookies.CookiesMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2019-04-01 16:27:17 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2019-04-01 16:27:17 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2019-04-01 16:27:17 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2019-04-01 16:27:17 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2019-04-01 16:27:17 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2019-04-01 16:27:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.latlong.net/robots.txt> (referer: None)
2019-04-01 16:27:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET https://www.latlong.net/> (referer: None)
2019-04-01 16:27:18 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <POST https://www.latlong.net/> (referer: https://www.latlong.net/)
2019-04-01 16:27:18 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.latlong.net/>
{'latlong': '0,0'}
2019-04-01 16:27:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-04-01 16:27:18 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 874,
 'downloader/request_count': 3,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
 'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 29252,
 'downloader/response_count': 3,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 3,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 14, 27, 18, 923987),
 'item_scraped_count': 1,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
 'log_count/INFO': 7,
 'request_depth_max': 1,
 'response_received_count': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 4, 1, 14, 27, 17, 773592)}
2019-04-01 16:27:18 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Comment: Can you post log of your running?

Comment: I've added the log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your parse method should be a generator, so you need to use `yield` instead of `return` on the for loop, otherwise you'll finish the loop on the first iteration. Furthermore, `get_get` method is returning a `set`, but it must return `Request`, `BaseItem`, `dict` or `None`.

I suggest changing the code as follow:

```
import scrapy
import json

with open('C:/Users/coppe/tutorial/cities.json') as json_file:  
    cities = json.load(json_file)

class communes_spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "geo"
    start_urls = ['https://www.latlong.net/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for city in cities:
            yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(response, formdata={'place': city['city']}, callback=self.get_geo)

    def get_geo(self, response):
        yield {'coord': response.css('span.coordinatetxt::text').get()}
```

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/use-yield-keyword-instead-return-keyword-python/

Comment: Thanks it works ! Yet I still have an issue. The website I take data from is not sending the correct data after the request form. The default value of the output is (0,0). If I request for a town the output should be for example (50.643909, 5.571560). But still the output of the crawler is (0,0). I guess there is an issue with the website ?